# Jquery/javascript onclick display next row

Tags: jquery, onclick, row, hidden, show

I have a table that has a row that is hidden using display:none. I want to show the row when a button is clicked. How can I do this??

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<button class="shownextrow">Show Next Row</button>
</td>
</tr>

<tr style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="input"/>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind to the button and find it relatively, like this:

```
$("button.shownextrow").click(function() { 
  $(this).closest("tr").next().show();
});
```

This goes from the button (`$(this)`) up to the `<tr>` using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) then gets the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling `<tr>` to [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).  You may want to use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) but the rest is the same.

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Fds5z/).  Note that you have a `<input>` directly in a `<tr>` in the example, I wrapped this in a `<td>` to make it a valid demo.

Comment: How can I also show a hidden object within the tr I have just shown??

Comment: @user342391 - I wouldn't hide anything inside...but you can tack on a `.find('whatever').show()` after the `.show()` in the example above to find/show something inside.

Answer (score 2):

[Nick's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805254/jquery-javsacript-onclick-display-next-row/3805268#3805268) is fine, but I'd probably use a single handler for the entire table ("event delegation") via the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function, rather than individual handlers on each button, like this:

```
$('#theTable').delegate("button.shownextrow", "click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").show();
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ayula3/2)

Amongst other things, that lets you add more pairs of rows to the table (and remove pairs of rows) without worrying about hooking up / unhooking event handlers for them. Mind, it does require that nothing directly in the hierarchy between the `button` element and the `table` element eats clicks...

---

Here's my older example that didn't use `delegate`, just for historical purposes — **wow** does `delegate` simplify the code:

```
$('#theTable').click(function(event) {
    var button = $(event.target).closest("button.shownextrow");
    if (button.length > 0) {
        button.closest("tr").next("tr").show();
    }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ayula3)

Comment: If you're doing to use delegation, use `.delegate()`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Fds5z/1/

Comment: @Nick: I was revising as you posted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the parent `tr` to show the next `tr`:

```
$('button.shownextrow').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').show();
});
```

I used it and it worked just fine.